# JFrogGradle@1 complains that it doesn't find any outputs

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have an issue with JFrog azure template complains that it doesn't produce any outputs, i.e. it does not deploy to JFrog. My guess is that it doesn't find a library to publish but it's just a guess since the error is no clearer than that.

I'm having a Kotlin Multiplatform project which builds an aar-library and iOS Framework. Now I want to publish the aar-library to JFrog. I can't add artifactoryPublish in the build.gradle.kts script cause it doesn't find the Jfrog imports (alternatively is if anyone can tell me how I add compile time library to build scripts?), so instead I'm using the JFrog Azure template instead (see code snippets below from JFrogs [webpage](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-azure-devops-extension).

The build produces standard build output from aar-library (build/outputs/aar..) and I have a maven-publish task:

```
publishing {

    publications {

        create<MavenPublication>("mavenAar") {
            groupId = group.toString()
            artifactId = "library-android"
            version = version
            from(components["kotlin"])
        }
    }
}
```

But using artifactoryPublish in gradle you provide an publishing task:

```
publications(publishing.publications["mavenAar"])
```

But with JFrog you don't seem to do that. So how does it find the artifact to publish? Or how can I use the artifactoryPublish task in a Kotlin MPP?

**Error message:**

```
023-12-06T21:03:14.730+0000 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :artifactoryDeploy
2023-12-06T21:03:14.730+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter] Putting task artifact state for task ':artifactoryDeploy' into context took 0.0 secs.
2023-12-06T21:03:14.730+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep] Caching disabled for task ':artifactoryDeploy' because:
  Build cache is disabled
2023-12-06T21:03:14.730+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep] Determining if task ':artifactoryDeploy' is up-to-date
2023-12-06T21:03:14.731+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep] Task ':artifactoryDeploy' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
```

**JFrogGradle@1 azure template:**

```
 task: JFrogGradle@1
  inputs:
    gradleBuildFile: 'build.gradle'
    tasks: 'artifactoryPublish'
    artifactoryResolverService: 'jfrog artifactory'
    sourceRepo: 'gradle-virtual'
    artifactoryDeployerService: 'jfrog artifactory'
    targetRepo: 'gradle-local'
```